# In practice, what's the fastest method to find a least square solution rather than using SVD decompostion?

Tags: algorithms, least-squares

I'm working on a real-time implementation of Lucas-Kanade for optical flow. However, the SVD decomposition to do achieve the least square method to reduce the error seems to take too much time.

A brief explanation of the algorithm can be accessed here [Lucas Kanade algorithm](http://www.inf.fu-berlin.de/inst/ag-ki/rojas_home/documents/tutorials/Lucas-Kanade2.pdf)

Comment: One might try using conjugate gradients in the case computing matrix factorizations like the SVD for one's problem is too computationally involving. This being said the computational complexity for each of these methods is in general $O(N^3)$.

Comment: I would recommend to try qr-factorization e.g. by using Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization.

Comment: @user35593 Why GS instead of Householder?

Answer (score 1):

Aren't the matrices in Lucas-Kanade tall and skinny? A Nx2 solve regardless of method should be fast; maybe you're computing a full SVD when you should be doing a reduced  one instead?

Answer (score 1):

In practice, the fastest direct method is normal equations $A^TAx=A^Tb$ + exploiting symmetry to compute $A^TA$ + Cholesky to solve the resulting linear system. It scales like $mn^2 + o(mn^2)$ for an $m\times n$ matrix $A$ with $m\gg n$, when most other algorithms cost $2mn^2$, and it is faster even in the case $m\approx n$. However, it may be dramatically unstable, especially if the value of that minimum norm is small.